# Zipping List of Pandas DataFrames Yields Unexpected Results

Tags: python, pandas

Can somebody explain the following code?

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3], "col2": [2,3,4]})
b = pd.DataFrame({"col3": [1,2,3], "col4": [2,3,4]})
list(zip(*[a,b]))
```

Output:

```
[('col1', 'col3'), ('col2', 'col4')]
```

Comment: see what `list(a)`  returns or any dictionary, for example `list({"A":1,"B":2})` , it always returns the keys (not the values), that justifies your result, what are you expecting bdw?

Answer (score 0):

a:

[image]

b:

[image]

---

zip function returns tuple:

```
a = ("John", "Charles", "Mike")
b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica", "Vicky")

x = zip(a, b)

#use the tuple() function to display a readable version of the result:

print(tuple(x))
```

[image]

---

with [a,b] inside zip - U get the whole values from df.

[image]

---

There is also combine the all possible combination (16 permutations) :

eg:

```
d = list(zip(a['col1'],b['col4']))
```

[image]